# How do you enable nested virtualization in Windows 10 Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10-preview

Windows 10's latest preview announced nested virtualization.  I was researching how to turn it on and wanted to share what I found.

Answer (score 1):

On the Windows 10 host machine, create the VM and use the name of the VM when issuing the following commands from an elevated PowerShell prompt:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/Virtualization-Documentation/master/hyperv-tools/Nested/Enable-NestedVm.ps1 -OutFile ~/Enable-NestedVm.ps1
```

Next Issue the following command from the same prompt:

```
 ~/Enable-NestedVm.ps1 -VmName <VmName>
```